# How do run object storage minio in a minikube cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, minio

I want to integrate a minio object storage in to my minikune cluster.

I use the docker file from the minio [gitrepo](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/Dockerfile)

I also added the persistent volume with the claim

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data/minio"
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

for the minio deployment I have

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minio
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
      role: master
      tier: backend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio
        role: master
        tier: backend
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: minio
          image: <secret Registry >
          env:
          - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
            value: akey
          - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
            value: skey
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data/ob
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: minio-pv-claim
```

For the service I opened up the external IP just for debugging

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.99.101 
  selector:
    app: minio
    role: master
    tier: backend
```

But when I start the deployment I get the error message `ERROR Unable to initialize backend: The disk size is less than the minimum threshold.`

I assumed that 3GB should be enough. How can I solve this issue moreover now that I try to delete my persistent volume it rest in the terminating status.

How can I run minio in a minikube clutster?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is enough storage in /mnt/data inside minikube.  Try /mnt/sda1 or /data.  Better yet, go inside minikube and check the storage available.  To get into minikube you can do minikube ssh.